# IOS 9 is blocking modal mobile links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

My website uses modal to display information that requires buttons to be clicked e.g. back and submit. Now the link appears to be broken even though it's target is another page. The page reloads on any button click.

This has been working thus far but some users have been having issues with submitting the information. When myself and my colleagues then tested what was causing the issue we found out that the problem was only affecting devices running iOS9.

We looked up some information and found it might be something to do with having an empty `href`.

```
    <ul>
        <li><a class="pop" href="#" target="#modal" data-id="deposit-funds.aspx">Deposit Funds</a> <span class="moreinfo" title="How to deposit funds into your investor account"></span></li>

        <!--<li><a class="pop" href="#" target="#modal" data-id="dynamic-invest.aspx">Dynamic Invest</a> <span class="moreinfo" title="Dynamic investing explained"></span></li>-->


        <!--<li><a class="pop" href="#" target="#modal" data-id="auto-invest.aspx">Auto Invest</a> <span class="moreinfo" title="Autoinvest guidelines, setting criteria and turning on and off"></span></li>-->


        <li><a class="pop" href="#" target="#modal" data-id="current-investments.aspx">Current Loans</a></li>

        <li><a class="pop" href="#" target="#modal" data-id="my-resale.aspx">My Resale Offerings</a></li>

        <li><a class="pop" href="#" target="#modal" data-id="completed-investments.aspx">Completed Loans</a></li>

        <li><a class="pop" href="#" target="#modal" data-id="bids-outstanding.aspx">Bids Outstanding</a></li>

        <li><a class="pop" href="#" target="#modal" data-id="my-transactions.aspx">Transaction History</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

If anybody has had the same problem or has any ideas on a potential fix a point in the right direction would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem a while back and if I remember correctly I update the href to `href="javascript:;"`. This tricks the browser in to running some empty javascript instead of doing nothing at all (which is why iOS blocks it, I believe). Your other javascript will also run on click as well.

I also believe I ventured down the path of changing the `<a>` tags to `<span>` tags; as far as I remember, this also worked, but wasn't a great fix for my problem.

Comment: Calling the empty javascript did not solve the problem. I'm also not sure how I feel about chaning all the `<a>` tags to `<span>` as this would require a massive HTML and CSS rework due to the amount of classes and referencing the tags and the tags content.

If this is the only fix them I guess it leaves no option?